# Unnecessary std::forward use in result_of example of cppreference

Tags: c++, c++11

On the [`std::result_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) page there is a section for a possible implementation. It has this piece of code:

```
template <class Base, class T, class Derived>
inline auto INVOKE(T Base::*&& pmd, Derived&& ref) ->
    decltype(forward<Derived>(ref).*forward<T Base::*>(pmd)) {
      return forward<Derived>(ref).*forward<T Base::*>(pmd);
}
```

The part that I think is unnecessary is the use of `std::forward<T Base::*>`. The signature for `T Base::*&& pmd` does not use a "universal reference" like `Derived&& ref` does. Therefore it's invariably an rvalue-reference to a pointer-to-member.

Is my understanding correct? Can the `forward<T Base::*>` be taken out?

Comment: Yes, forwarding the member-pointer is unneccessary. (BTW: It's a shame `INVOKE` is not part of the standard library.)

Comment: @Deduplicator I and the author of [N4169](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4169.html) agree that `invoke` should be in the standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value category of the second operand (that is, the pointer-to-member) is not significant for a pointer-to-member operator.
Thus the `forward` is indeed superfluous, and the overload could be rewritten as

```
template <class Base, class T, class Derived>
inline auto INVOKE(T Base::*&& pmd, Derived&& ref) ->
    decltype(forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd) {
      return forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd;
}
```

The author probably copy&pasted the template "template" and didn't bother removing unnecessary forwards.

Answer (score 0):

[The edit from 2014-07-27 changed the pointer-to-member argument of that particular `INVOKE` overload from `PMD&& pmd` to `T Base::*&& pmd`](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/types/result_of&diff=72239&oldid=72189) with the comment "fix a bug when `ObjectRef` has an overloaded indirect operator that return itself." I'm not sure to what bug the comment refers, given that `.*` is not overloadable, but it did [introduce a new bug by *requiring* the pointer-to-member to be an rvalue](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e88fbdf5624f6132).

I fixed the bug by changing the two affected overloads to take the pointer-to-member by value; I'm hesitant to back out the change completely. Can anyone demonstrate the problem to which the edit refers?

Comment: I think it would make a better new question than an answer. :) I cannot see the bug either, FWIW.